# Terraform - Get a value from parameter store and pass to resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We store our latest approved AMIs in AWS parameter store. When creating new instances with Terraform I would like to programatically get this AMI ID. I have a command to pull the AMI ID but I'm not sure how to use it with Terraform.

Here is the command I use to pull the AMI ID:

```sh
$(aws ssm get-parameter --name /path/to/ami --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text)
```

And here is my Terraform script:

```
resource "aws_instance" "nginx" {
  ami           = "ami-c58c1dd3" # pull value from parameter store
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  #key_name        = "${var.key_name}"

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install nginx -y",
      "sudo service nginx start"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I use the command to pull the AMI ID in the Terraform script?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the [`aws_ssm_parameter` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter) to fetch the value of a parameter at runtime:

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ami" {
  name = "/path/to/ami"
}

resource "aws_instance" "nginx" {
  ami           = data.aws_ssm_parameter.ami.value # pull value from parameter store
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install nginx -y",
      "sudo service nginx start"
    ]
  }
}
```

However, a better approach might be to use the [`aws_ami` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html) to filter for the AMI you want more directly instead of pushing the AMI ID to SSM parameter store and then looking it up later. You can filter on a number of criteria including name, account owner and tags. Here's the example from the [`aws_instance` resource documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) that is looking for the latest Ubuntu 20.04 AMI:

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't use your second option as our ami's go through an approval process by another team and are then posted in parameter store for us to use. First option works perfect though

Comment: Your other team could apply a specific tag that you filter for. Might work, might not but thought it was worth suggesting as an idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it necessary to use string interpolation here? Can't you do `ami = data.aws_ssm_parameter.ami.value` without quoting it?

Comment: Yes but the question used the HCL1 syntax so the answer also used it. HCL2 syntax allows both but will warn on the unnecessary interpolation there.

Comment: Updated the answer to HCL2 syntax as 0.12 came out long enough ago that I'm slowly updating answers to HCL2 syntax even where the original question was 0.11 unless the question specifically wanted a HCL1/0.11 answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use this approach since you already have the AMI ID stored at AWS SSM:

```
resource "aws_instance" "nginx" {
   ami           = data.aws_ssm_parameter.ami.value
   instance_type = "t2.micro"

   provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install nginx -y",
      "sudo service nginx start"
    ]
   }
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ami" {
  name = "/production/ami"
}
```